# Gradle: Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig_Decorated

Tags: gradle, jenkins

I have an issue with Gradle running on Jenkins:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig_Decorated.
```

Top level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Line the error occurrs on (file app/build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I tried using Gradle wrapper/Invoke Gradle, and with different versions down to 2.10. I'm using "Force GRADLE_USER_HOME to use workspace".

Comment: Getting the same error, were you able to fix it? @David8

Comment: @Harshit Unfortunately I still don't have solution. Maybe this error is related to permissons or package signing. But if you would somehow solve it, I'll be glad if you'll share the solution.

Comment: Hey,
I was compiling the apk on the apache-server, so the issue was related to permissions.
Turned out that the user was not authorized to write in the project directory.
I updated its permission to 777 and it worked.
Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue after updating to Gradle 2.10. I had to create a folder named /usr/share/tomcat/.android and give it all permissions (chmod a+rwx .android). That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I don't have the `/usr/share/tomcat` folder, what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

You are probably missing the Android SDK build tools. If you open the gradle.build file using Android Studio it can help you install the required tools. Or have a look at [How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line)